# How do I intercept mouse release events on a QWidget without subclassing it?

Tags: qt5

I am writing an application that has a UI manager, allowing the user to add and remove widgets from a main window and configure them. When the user ctrl-alt-right clicks the widget I need to open a configuration dialog for the widget to allow the user to change various properties.

I have a class that inherits from a pure virtual base class so that all the managed widgets can be managed using a common interface. I have a sub-class that detects the ctrl-alt-right click. Widget managers then inherit from that sub-class.

```
Managed widget virtual base class (ViewElement)
                     |
                     V
    Clickable sub-class (ClickableElement)
   /                 |                    \
  V                  V                     V
Label widget     Button widget         etc. etc.
```

Each widget manager contains one or more Qt widgets of some sort.

Because the managed widget can be made up of multiple Qt Widgets, and because the ClickableElement class is a base class of the widget manager which actually knows what sort of Qt Widget it is managing, the ClickableElement class cannot inherit from QWidget.

I need the ClickableElement class to be able to detect when there is a mouse release event on the Qt widget(s). Because ClickableElement cannot inherit from the managed QWidget instance for the reasons described below, **I cannot implement `virtual mouseReleaseEvent()`**.

I do not want to implement hundreds of sub-classes, one for each Qt widget type, just so I can implement `virtual mouseReleaseEvent()` and have it send a custom signal.

Thus I need to connect() a slot to the relevant signal from the QWidget instance.

What signal does a QWidget send when a mouse release event occurs on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ClickableElement class header, declare `eventFilter()` as follows:

```
bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override;
```

Implement the function along these lines:

```
bool ClickableElement::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (QEvent::MouseButtonRelease == event->type()) {
        QMouseEvent *mouse_event = dynamic_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);

        ...

    }

    if (!result) {
        result = QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }

    return result;
}
```

In the subclass for each widget type, make this call:

```
m_widget->installEventFilter(this);
```